# c# API call ends without response.Result statement

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Below is a generic class we use to make our API calls.  I have a few calls that REQUIRE the statement `var notSureWhyWeNeedThisButWeDo = response.Result;` below to make it work, and others calls don't need it at all.  Can someone explain why this is needed and there must be a better way to code this?

```
public class APICallClass
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> APICall(AccessTokenObject root, string json, string paCode, string url, string type)
    {
        try {
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            data.Headers.Add("securityToken", root.access_token);
            if (paCode.Length > 0) {
                data.Headers.Add("X-POS-MerchantID", paCode);
            }

            Task<HttpResponseMessage> response;

            switch (type) {
                case "put":
                    response = client.PutAsync(url, data);
                    break;
                case "post":
                    response = client.PostAsync(url, data);
                    break;
                default:
                    response = client.PostAsync(url, data);
                    break;
            }

            var notSureWhyWeNeedThisButWeDo = response.Result;

            return await response.ConfigureAwait(false);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logging.WriteErrorMessage(Priority.High, string.Empty, "APICall",  "APICall.cs",url, ex, "client.xxxxAsync", false);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm makings calls to this with statements like:

```
var response = await TalechAPI.APICall(root, json, pa.storeId, "https://mapi.talech.com/managemenu/menuitem/allmenuitems", "post");
```

After the call, we do things like this:

```
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    AddMenuItem.AddMenuItemRoot hd = JToken.Parse(result).ToObject<AddMenuItem.AddMenuItemRoot>();

    if ((int) response.StatusCode != 200) {
        Logging.WriteErrorMessage(Priority.High, string.Empty, "Talech", "Items.cs", "RootInsertItem", response.StatusCode.ToString(), "TalechBatchUser", false);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: No, they [don't require](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) `response.Result`. This line is wrong and you may be getting away with it in case it completes really fast. The next line is correct.

Comment: FYI, when you have this in debug the response.Result will force the async operation to be synchronous but when compiled for release this will be compiled out.

Comment: You also need to make sure the caller to this function is awaiting it or else it might never complete.

Comment: @MatthewWhited How can an already compiled asynchronous operation to be compiled as synchronous, and how can a call to a property be compiled out?

Comment: That's how the optimizer works.  the variable is never used so the optimizer can toss it.  Never trust code like this.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I would be surprised to learn that in C# a call to a property getter [that causes side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319430/11683) (which `.Result` does) may be optimized out. Can you demonstrate?

Comment: Yeah, compile the above code in release and cross your fingers when it throw an exception.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I take that you cannot.

Comment: All I know is, if that statement is commented out, the program does not make that API call, and it doesn't matter whether I'm debugging it in VS or running the executable standalone.  If it's not commented out the program works as expected, debugging or standalone.  And my API call URLs work just fine in Postman.

Comment: @Craig How are you calling `APICall`?

Comment: I posted an example in the code section above.

Comment: That is the correct way to call it. That function that calls it as `await TalechAPI.APICall`, is it in turn correctly called, all the way up? Do you have any `.Result`s anywhere along the chain?

Comment: Even if the compiler doesn’t remove the .Result it will still force synchronization to that point (better than random failure but defeats the purpose of async/await.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I think you are getting the awaiter and configuring it,but that does not wait for execution (you wait for the configure await response).
The call you make to read the result is what forces the call to be synchronous because result is not available until after it is completed.

```
switch (type) {
  case "put":
    return await client.PutAsync(url, data);                   
  case "post":
    return await client.PostAsync(url, data);
  default:
    return await client.PostAsync(url, data);
}
```

Is all that is needed to return the response once it is completed.

Comment: `that does not wait for execution (you wait for the configure await response)` - no.

Comment: I did try this prior to your post and it too completely makes the program stop!

Comment: That is unfortunate. Craig. I compiled this application locally and experienced your described behavior. Then making the changes as shown here resolved it.

Comment: CSerg, when you say no, why is that? Microsoft documentation specifically states that is what you are doinghttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.configureawait?view=net-6.0

Comment: GSerg, 
The object you receive from the ConfigureAwait call is of type ConfiguredAsyncDisposable
"Provides a type that can be used to configure how awaits on an IAsyncDisposable are performed."